# Как добавить первую часть строк не переводя их

Tags: python

У меня есть код:

```
from googletrans import *
translator = Translator()
zapros = input('Введите название файла с расширением (пр. example.lang): ')
with open(zapros,encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip().split('=')[1] for line in file if '=' in line]
result = translator.translate(lines, src='en', dest='ru')
for i in result: print(i.text)
```

Тут в выходе из файла печатается только 2 часть и переводится, но нужно, чтобы первая часть также печаталась, но не переводилась.

Comment: Дай кусочек данных из файла что читается в коде, помогу сделать

Comment: achievement.xu2.water.mill=Water Mill
achievement.xu2.water.mill.desc=The Flow of Water
achievement.xu2.wind.mill=Wind Mill
achievement.xu2.wind.mill.desc=Winds light to variable
achievement.xu2.wrench=Wrench
achievement.xu2.wrench.desc=Wrench it!

attribute.name.extrautils2.armorpiercingattackdamage=Armor Piercing Damage
attribute.name.extrautils2.godslayingattackdamage=Divine Damage
attribute.name.extrautils2.souldamage=Permanent Damage

Comment: achievement.xu2.water.mill=Water Mill achievement.xu2.water.mill.desc=The Flow of Water
Что из этого первая часть, а что второя?

Comment: всё что перед знаком = - 1 часть, всё что после, 2

Comment: Ну смотри, в lines записывается только вторая часть строки, соответственно, она и переводится

Comment: откуда 1 достать,мне нужно первую тоже писать, но не переводить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from googletrans import *
translator = Translator()
zapros = input('Введите название файла с расширением (пр. example.lang): ')
with open(zapros, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip().split('=') for line in file if '=' in line]

for i in lines:
    i[-1] = translator.translate(i[-1], src='en', dest='ru').text
    print('='.join(i))
```

Попробуй так, разбиваем по знаку "=" и последний элемент списка переводим

Comment: А вообще переменная 'zapros' такое себе 

Comment: Норм работает, но как убрать из вывода скобки и кавычки

Comment: У меня нету скобок. напиши сюда что выводится, возможно из исходно файла читается не как у меня, у тебя через print вывод или через pprint?

Comment: а не уже не надо, сделал print(i[0],i[1])